# Find Max & Min of one column and difference of two other columns in Python

Tags: python, calculated-columns

I am working on a table named **kpi** where I need to calculate the difference of (latest B1 - earliest B0) for each BoxID per week using the Minimum **No.** and Maximum **No.** for each **BoxID** per **week**, so you will need to use the minimum value of No. and use the corresponding B0 and use the max value of No. and use the corresponding B1, then find the difference. -
I coded in R with some help, but now I need the code in Python too.

```
kpi %>%
  group_by(BoxID, WkNo) %>%
  mutate(i = which.min(No.), 
         j = which.max(No.)) %>%
  mutate(First_B0 = B0[i],
         Last_B1 = B1[j],
         Diff = Last_B1 - First_B0) %>%
  select(-i, -j)
```

**Input table -**

```
Date      No.   BoxID B0      B1      WkNo
29.10.2018  61931   1   0       0       44
15.11.2018  115763  1   5.38    5.38    46
16.11.2018  119833  1   51.86   52.23   46
29.10.2018  60486   3   23.26   22.97   44
10.11.2018  99576   3   1336.53 1336.53 45
14.11.2018  112259  3   1.19    1.04    46
16.11.2018  117965  3   8.68    47.22   46
16.11.2018  118092  3   47.22   47.22   46
15.11.2018  115396  4   82.05   82.05   46
```

**Expected output table -**

```
Date        No.   BoxID B0      B1      WkNo   First_b1     Last_b0  Diff
29.10.2018  61931   1   0       0       44     0            0        0
15.11.2018  115763  1   5.38    5.38    46     52.23        5.38     46.85
16.11.2018  119833  1   51.86   52.23   46     52.23        5.38     46.85
29.10.2018  60486   3   23.26   22.97   44     22.97        23.26    -0.29
10.11.2018  99576   3   1336.53 1336.53 45     1336.53      1336.53  0
14.11.2018  112259  3   1.19    1.04    46     47.22        1.19     46.03
16.11.2018  117965  3   8.68    47.22   46     47.22        1.19     46.03
16.11.2018  118092  3   47.22   47.22   46     47.22        1.19     46.03
15.11.2018  115396  4   82.05   82.05   46     82.05       82.05     0
```

I need some help to compute the 3 more columns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it sql table or Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, these types of problems are best solved using the pandas library. As an R user, you'll find the dataframes easy to work with, since pandas was designed to be very much like R.

Assuming your table is a .csv file called "kpi.csv"...

```
>>import pandas as pd

>>df = pd.read_csv('kpi.csv')   

>>df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(['BoxID','WkNo'])['No.'].idxmax(),['BoxID','WkNo','B1']]
>>df3 = df.loc[df.groupby(['BoxID','WkNo'])['No.'].idxmin(),['BoxID','WkNo','B0']]

>>df = df.merge(df2,on=['BoxID','WkNo'])
>>df = df.merge(df3,on=['BoxID','WkNo'])

>>df = df.rename(columns = {'B0_x' : 'B0',
                          'B1_x' : 'B1',
                          'B1_y' : 'First_b1',
                          'B0_y' : 'Last_b0'})

>>df['Diff'] = df['First_b1'] - df['Last_b0']
>>print(df)




         Date     No.  BoxID       B0  ...    WkNo  First_b1  Last_b0   Diff
0  29.10.2018   61931      1     0.00  ...      44      0.00     0.00   0.00
1  15.11.2018  115763      1     5.38  ...      46     52.23     5.38  46.85
2  16.11.2018  119833      1    51.86  ...      46     52.23     5.38  46.85
3  29.10.2018   60486      3    23.26  ...      44     22.97    23.26  -0.29
4  10.11.2018   99576      3  1336.53  ...      45   1336.53  1336.53   0.00
5  14.11.2018  112259      3     1.19  ...      46     47.22     1.19  46.03
6  16.11.2018  117965      3     8.68  ...      46     47.22     1.19  46.03
7  16.11.2018  118092      3    47.22  ...      46     47.22     1.19  46.03
8  15.11.2018  115396      4    82.05  ...      46     82.05    82.05   0.00
```

Comment: You will need to find out the B1 for the Max "No." and B0 for the Min "No.". The difference between the earliest B0 and latest B1. B is Balance. So I am trying to find out the balance in a week.

Comment: Hi - I updated the code in my original answer to conform to your request.

Comment: Can you please approve my answer or provide feedback?